# Google Appscript insert column in array

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to know how to insert a column into an array. I know the push function to add a row but not how to add a column like that:

```
A ; 1
B ; 2
C ; 3
D ; 4
```

To:

```
A ; A1 ; 1
B ; B2 ; 2
C ; C3 ; 3
D ; D4 ; 4
```

I guess I will have to loop between each row to add an item between two item but is there a way to do it as a bulk?

Comment: For Google Sheets?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yes for Google Sheets - Appscript more precisely

Comment: I added an example Apps Script [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78244617/1762224).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let a = [["A",1],["B",2],["C",3],["D",4]];
    let b = a.map( row => [row[0],row[0]+row[1],row[1]]);
    console.log(b);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err)
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
8:11:48 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:11:49 AM  Info    [ [ 'A', 'A1', 1 ],
  [ 'B', 'B2', 2 ],
  [ 'C', 'C3', 3 ],
  [ 'D', 'D4', 4 ] ]
8:11:49 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Arror function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Sorry it was for Appscript not javascript, but thanks!

Comment: @HoucemFattah That javascript will run on the google server.  And clearly it is running  on the server because the execution log is part of the answer.

Comment: You right, I learned one thing today then. I think it's the right solution but could you please explain what is "row" ? And what if I want to have 10 columns, then the concatenated column, then 10 more ?

Comment: I've added a reference to the javascript Arror function `row =>`

Answer (score 0):

You can splice the concatenated values of the left and right columns.

The following Apps Script should work:

> ***Note:** The `index` is the position of the column you will be inserting after.*

```js
const __spliceAndMap = (rows, index, mapFn) =>
  rows.map((row) =>
    row.toSpliced(index + 1, 0, mapFn(row[index], row[index + 1])));

const __addColumn = (sheet, index, mapFn) => {
  let range = sheet.getDataRange();

  // Concatenate values and set them in the new column
  const updatedRows = __spliceAndMap(range.getValues(), index, mapFn);

  // Insert a new column after columnIndex
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(index + 1);
  
  // Update the sheet with the new values
  range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, updatedRows.length, updatedRows[0].length);
  range.setValues(updatedRows);
}

function concatenateColumns() {
  // Get the active sheet
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  // Add a column after index 0 and concatenate the left and right values
  __addColumn(sheet, 0, (left, right) => left + right);
}
```

Here is a demo of the `__spliceAndMap` being used:

```js
const __spliceAndMap = (rows, index, mapFn) =>
  rows.map((row) =>
    row.toSpliced(index + 1, 0, mapFn(row[index], row[index + 1])));

const interpolate = (str, delim = '\t', sep = '\n') => {
  const rows = str.trim().split(sep).map(ln => ln.split(delim));
  return __spliceAndMap(rows, 0, (left, right) => left + right)
    .map(row => row.join(delim)).join(sep);
};

// Output:
// A ; A1 ; 1
// B ; B2 ; 2
// C ; C3 ; 3
// D ; D4 ; 4
console.log(interpolate(`
A ; 1
B ; 2
C ; 3
D ; 4
`, ' ; '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function insertcol() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const o = vs.map(([a,b]) => [a,a+b,b]);
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 2,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Input and Output

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |  |
| 2 | B | 2 |  |
| 3 | C | 3 |  |
| 4 | D | 4 |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |
| 6 | A | A1 | 1 |
| 7 | B | B2 | 2 |
| 8 | C | C3 | 3 |
| 9 | D | D4 | 4 |

```
function insertcol() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const o = vs.map(([a,b,c,d,e,f,g]) => [a,f+g,b]);
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 2,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

input and output

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 | F1 | G1 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 | F2 | G2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 | F3 | G3 |
| 4 | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 | F4 | G4 |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | A1 | F1G1 | B1 |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | A2 | F2G2 | B2 |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | A3 | F3G3 | B3 |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | A4 | F4G4 | B4 |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Thanks ! But what if instead of having columns a then a+b then b I want a:f then f+g then g:z ?

Comment: You should spend some time studying Tanaike's answers he does this sort of thing in many of his answers and in many different situations.

Comment: Who is Tanaike ?

Comment: This is his user number:`7108653` User the tools on the search box to learn how to use them.